# Debugging with dap-mode for python and taking user input

Tags: spacemacs, osx, debugging, debug, lsp

I am trying to make dap-mode for python working on spacemacs.

For the most part I was able to get it working, but I am having issues taking in input on the CLI

```
def main():
  a = input(">")
```

The debug pane

```
-*- mode: dap-server-log; default-directory: "~/test2/" -*-
Debug Adapter started at Sun Jan 12 15:32:25

/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/bin/python -m ptvsd --wait --host localhost --port 32000  /Users/user/test2/main.py 
>
```

**Problem:** can't type user input in the debug pane

---

I found a potential solution here, but couldn't quite get it working.

https://github.com/emacs-lsp/dap-mode/issues/169
https://github.com/emacs-lsp/dap-mode/issues/97

I tried using the configurations below on osx but get an error:

`(setq dap-python-terminal "iterm ")`
but I get `zsh:1: command not found: iterm`
and

`(setq dap-python-executable "iterm")`
but I get `wrong type argument: arrayp, nil`

also tried `(setq dap-python-terminal "open -a Terminal ")`

**Env**
osx, iterm, spacemacs/emacs, zsh, python

**Note**:
I know how to use pdb, but really like the dap-ui on spacemacs so I'd prefer to use that layer if I can get this one small issue sorted out.

---

**Edit**:
It has something to do with the executable of iterm on my machine

Since iterm doesn't have a default executable on osx, after some searching it looks like I had to write an osascript. I wrote one and put it on my path

```
osascript <<EOD
  tell application "iTerm"
    create window with default profile
  end tell
EOD
```

```
-*- mode: dap-server-log; default-directory: "~/test2/" -*-
Debug Adapter started at Mon Jan 13 22:39:29

iterm /Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/bin/python -m ptvsd --wait --host localhost --port 32000  /Users/user/test2/main.py 
window id 11705

Debug Adapter finished at Mon Jan 13 22:39:29
```

It starts up a new window, but doesn't go into debugging mode.

Comment: My guess is that iterm is not on the path. Can you execute `(executable-find "iterm")`? You may edit spacemacs environment via `SPC f e e`.